# How to run only one feature file when running protractor with cucumber?

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I have multiple feature files and I would really love to run just one file or just one scenario or just one tag.
I know I could just provide one file in my specs in my cucumberConf.js, but I would like to run it once without fiddling with my cucumberConf.js.
Which arguments do I need to type in when running protractor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the `--specs` option.

`protractor --specs=specs/testA.js e2e-conf.js`

Answer (score 7):

in protractor's config:

```
cucumberOpts: {
...
        tags: [
        "@runThis",
        "@runThat",
        "~@ignoreThis"
    ];
...
},
```

in the feature file

```
    @runThis
    Scenario: Run this Scenario
        Given user does some action
        Then something should happen

    @ignoreThis
    Scenario: ignore this Scenario
        Given user does some action
        Then something should happen
```

Comment: So using the tilde `~` will ignore that tag?

Answer (score 2):

use the specs array in protractor config file. E.g.

```
specs: [ 'test/features/xxx.feature' ],
```